# Writing Binary to .Xlsx

Tags: c#, lambda

Hello I have the below class I am using to download Excel Files from sql server using Linq to Sql in WPF.  I am having problems getting the method to work.

```
public class Tables
            {
                public Guid Id { get; set; }
                public byte[] Data { get; set; }
                public string Notes{ get; set; }            
            }
```

Property

```
public ObservableCollection<Tables> Table
        {
            get
            {
                return mTables;
            }
        }
```

The method (Error - fileBytes does not appear in the current context)

```
 private void executeSaveAttachment(object parameter)
            {
                //Enables the apperance of a Dialog, where the user can specify where to save the file
                SaveFileDialog textDialog = new SaveFileDialog();

                //save the file in a bite array

               // byte[] fileBytes = Table.ToList().ForEach(p => p.Data);
                Table.ToList().ForEach(p =>
                {
                    byte[] fileBytes = p.Data;
                });

                //Open dialog where the user determines where to save the file.
                bool? result = textDialog.ShowDialog();
                if (result == true)
                {
                    using (Stream fs = (Stream)textDialog.OpenFile())
                    {
                        fs.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                        fs.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your `fileBytes` array is initialized inside a loop so it is not available in the context of your `if` statement below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because `fileBytes` only exists within the delegate passed to ForEach. Try this:

```
private void executeSaveAttachment(object parameter)
{
    using (var dlg = new SaveFileDialog())
    {
        foreach (var table in Table)
        {
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() ?? false)
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(dlg.FileName, table.Data)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 'Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

Comment: There are 3 SaveFileDialog classes in the .NET framework: one for WinForms (System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog),  one for WPF (System.Windows.Controls.SaveFileDialog) and one in the Microsoft.Win32 namespace (not toally sure what that last one is for). If you are using WinForms, use the first one, and it is disposable, so use the using keyword. If you're using either of the other ones, they aren't disposable, and you can remove the using keyword.

Answer (score 0):

For WPF

```
private void executeSaveAttachment(object parameter)
        {
            SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
            {
                foreach (var table in Table)
                {
                    if (dlg.ShowDialog() ?? false)
                    {
                        File.WriteAllBytes(dlg.FileName, table.Data);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```